# Ошибка в БД при запуске приложения

Tags: база-данных, kotlin, исключения, android-room

При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка `RuntimeException`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.notemvpkotlin, PID: 2057
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.notemvpkotlin.data.App: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.notemvpkotlin.data.NotesDatabase. NotesDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.notemvpkotlin.data.NotesDatabase. NotesDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:952)
        at com.example.notemvpkotlin.data.App.onCreate(App.kt:25) //Строка создания БД
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5361)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Код создания БД. Вероятно ошибка кроется именно там, так как на `Kotlin` Room применяю впервые и мог где то ошибиться, но самостоятельно определить ошибку не выходит.

```
class App: Application() {

    companion object {
        private const val DB_NAME: String = "notes.db"
        var database: NotesDatabase? = null
        private var instance: App? = null

        fun getInstance(): App? {
            return instance
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, NotesDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
    }

    fun getDatabase(): NotesDatabase? {
        return database
    }
}
```

Класс `App` добавлен в манифест.
Манифест:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".data.App"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

И на всякий случай `build.gradle`. Возможно не добавил какие то зависимости.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'

    def room_version = "2.2.5"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    def nav_version = "2.3.0"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

Класс NotesDatabase:

```
abstract class NotesDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun notesDao(): NotesDao
}
```

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть класс NotesDatabase

Comment: @ivan Добавил класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс БД NotesDatabase должен отмечаться аннотацией такой как:
`@Database(entities = arrayOf(Notes::class), version = 1)`

Так же не забудьте добавить плагин `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` (обработчик аннотаций) в `build.gradle` приложения.

Пример из офф документации: [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я совсем про это забыл.

Comment: @zel1b0baa, обращайтесь :)